# How can I include a library in a React app just for development purposes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a React app that will be included in a website that already has Twitter Bootstrap and styles. I need to include Twitter Bootstrap for development purposes but not as part of the final product as styles will be fed into the app through the parent app. What is the best way to fulfill this pattern?

Comment: In what way child app will be embedded into the parent?

Comment: Think of a larger app that loads Twitter Bootstrap, the React App will use the styles from that app to stylize itself but we do not need to bundle React in it.

Comment: I mean how you embed second app? Iframe? Module/Component?

Answer (score 0):

> "devDependencies": Packages that are only needed for local development and testing.
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file